# AngularJS ng-Grid cursor navigation in grid textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

In my project I am using ng-grid, Grid is working fine, but there is a problem in textarea like:

1. When we type something in the textarea we are unable to navigate using left arrow and right arrow but we can select through mouse, also backspace is working as usual.

When I googled I find some suggestion to check for keycode== 37 or keycode==39, and to find whether there is any preventDefault() for above keys but I could not find any such code, is there any other alternative

Comment: actually I find the reason for the above problem. The problem was in the cellTemplate not in ng-grid. I modified the cellTemplate and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Can you please post what you did to solve this exactly? I have the exact same problem. Thanks.